# TCP Socket - How to connect to server socket, then close it and connect again?

Tags: c, sockets, tcp

This code isn't 100% correct but I need my program to do something like this.

Client

```
fd = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
    if(fd==-1) exit(1);

n = connect(fd,res->ai_addr,res->ai_addrlen);
    if(n==-1) exit(1);

char buffer[128] = read(fd,buffer,128);
if(strcmp(buffer,"Done\n")==0) close(fd);

n = connect(fd,res->ai_addr,res->ai_addrlen);
    if(n==-1) exit(1);

bzero(buffer,128);
read(fd,buffer,128);
if(strcmp(buffer,"Done\n")==0) close(fd);
```

Server

```
listenfd = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
if(listenfd == -1) exit(1);

n=bind(listenfd,res2->ai_addr, res2->ai_addrlen);
if(n==-1) exit(1);

if(listen(listenfd,10) == -1) exit(1);

while(1){
     User_fd = accept(listenfd,(struct sockaddr*)&addr2,&addrlen2);
            if(User_fd == -1){
                perror("accept");
                exit(1);
            }
     char buffer[5] = "Done\n";
     write(User_fd,buffer,5);
     close(User_fd);
}
```

When I try to connect the second time it gives me an error "Bad file descriptor". I've tried to create a new socket on the client each time we need to connect again but it affects the other sockets I have (with different servers) and I don't think it's a good thing to do.

Comment: My actual program doesn't receive "Done\n" but it has received the "verification message" needed to close the socket

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One cannot connect a socket twice, no matter if closed in between. One has to create a new socket instead.

Comment: Our problem is that when we create another socket to connect to this server, the other sockets we have that are connecting to other servers start malfunctioning.

Comment: @tomaslb26: Then you have a bug in your (unknown) code. But that does not change the fact that you cannot connect a socket twice.

Comment: Ok, thank you @Steffen Ullrich. We managed to solve it by setting the "fd" that we close to -1 right after closing it.